# Running a job on multiple nodes in parallel in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

Is there a possibility that a job can be run in parallel [it has only one task] on all the target nodes [15 nodes precisely]?

Also, will the Thread Count option in rundeck GUI solve the above purpose?

PS: I only have GUI access to Rundeck

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispatch your job to your 15 nodes, and set ThreadCount = 15. I did an example with 3 nodes (node00,node01 and node02) to understand it:

```xml
    <joblist>
      <job>
        <defaultTab>summary</defaultTab>
        <description></description>
        <dispatch>
          <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
          <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
          <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
          <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
          <threadcount>3</threadcount>
        </dispatch>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>c4a37a41-db35-4a76-b407-be6170c6502d</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobRemoteParallel</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <nodefilters>
          <filter>node.*</filter>
        </nodefilters>
        <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
          <command>
            <exec>sleep 2; echo "starting"</exec>
          </command>
          <command>
            <exec>sleep 5; echo "processing"</exec>
          </command>
          <command>
            <exec>echo "done!"</exec>
          </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>c4a37a41-db35-4a76-b407-be6170c6502d</uuid>
      </job>
    </joblist>
```

[Check](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/51376003/64790230-2070b980-d54c-11e9-89fd-be2be21e56bb.gif) how works.

Comment: Perfect! Docs are not clear on this but your answer was helpful.